# CSS Diagonal Image Overlap that expands to full width when hovered

Tags: html, css, transition

Hi I'm trying to create a collage of three images, like the concept shown in this site: https://codepen.io/zacharybrady/pen/aGmFp

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="diagonal" id="d0">

  <img src="http://www.shortpacked.com/comics/2013-02-08-prologue.png" />
  <p class="overlay">
    TEST
  </p>

  </div>

  <div class="diagonal" id="d1">

  <img src="http://www.questionablecontent.net/comics/2381.png" />
    <p class="overlay">
    TEST
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="diagonal" id="d2">

  <img src="http://www.shortpacked.com/comics/2005-01-17-bow-before-your-master.gif" />
    <p class="overlay">
    TEST
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="diagonal" id="d3">

  <img src="http://www.questionablecontent.net/comics/2021.png" />
    <p class="overlay">
    TEST
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="diagonal" id="d4">

  <img src="http://www.shortpacked.com/comics/2009-03-27-fourohfour.png" />
    <p class="overlay">
    TEST
  </p>
  </div>



</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import "compass/css3";

body{
  background: blue;
}

.container{
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;

.diagonal{
  height: 1200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include rotate(25deg);
   position: absolute;
   top: -200px;

  img{
     @include rotate(-25deg);
    margin-top: -100px;
      margin-left: -200px;
  }

    .overlay{
      @include rotate(-25deg);
      height: 1200px;
      width: 800px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -50px;
      left: 0;
      background: black;
      opacity: 0;
      color: white;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;

      &:hover{
        opacity: .8;
      }
    }

  &#d0{
      left: -180px;

    }

    &#d1{
      left: 40px;
    } 

     &#d2{
      left: 260px;

    } 

     &#d3{
      left: 480px;

    } 

    &#d4{
      left: 700px;

    } 

}
}
```

Question: How can I add additional transitions that when a specific image is hovered, it will expand to its full width?

PLEASE DON'T MARK this as duplicate or close this for having ambiguous question, because I know and you know the question there is clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the z-axis on hover, so that the full image comes to the front.

Comment: i don't think the import compass/css works when i tried testing it offline. only the first image displayed. How is that?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific with what your problem is.